# In odoo 10, using the UI I cannot get my "Server action +Automated action" to work

Tags: python, odoo-10

I have the "reviewer" field available in my task, and I want to switch the reviewer with the task assignee automatically when the task is moved from the 'In progress' stage to the 'Review' stage. I have the following Python code in my server action:
[picture of the code in context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2rdK.png)

```
def assignrev(self):
for record in self:
    if record['project.task.type.stage_id.name']=='Review':
        a=self.res.users.reviewer_id.name
        b=self.res.users.user_id.name
        record['res.users.user_id.name']=a
        record['res.users.reviewer_id.name']=b
```

and below are links to pictures of my automated action settings:
[Server action to run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNOYA.png)

["When to run" settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAS6O.png)

Unfortunately, changing the task stage to 'Review' does not give the expected results. Any suggestion please?

Kazu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I finally got the answer to this. below is a picture of the code in context for Odoo 10:
[image]

No "def" of "for record" needed: the code will not run.

I just hope this will be helpful to someone else...

Kazu

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are incorrectly calling the fields you're trying to get.

```
# Instead of this
a = self.res.users.reviewer_id.name
b = self.res.users.user_id.name
record['res.users.user_id.name']=a
record['res.users.reviewer_id.name']=b

# Try this
# You don't need to update the name, you need to update the database ID reference
record['user_id'] = record.reviewer_id.id
record['reviewer_id'] = record.user_id.id
```

Furthermore, why don't you try using an [`onchange` method](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#onchange-updating-ui-on-the-fly) instead?

```
@api.multi
def onchange_state(self):
    for record in self:
        if record.stage_id.name == 'Review':
            record.update({
                'user_id': record.reviewer_id.id,
                'reviewer_id': record.user_id.id,
            })
```

If you're still having problems, you can use [ipdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) to debug your code more easily by triggering `set_trace` in your method.

```
def assignrev(self):
    # Triggers a break in code so that you can debug
    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
    for record in self:
        # Test line by line with the terminal to see where your problem is
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer travisw, the problem is that as you can see in the pictures, I am using the action server pyhton code which seems to be limited. when I try to 'from odoo import api' in order to use the onchange method, I get the error: forbidden opcode(s) in u. It feels like I can only use  a trimmed down version of python...

Comment: Also, changing the syntax as indicated in your first suggestion didn't yield any result unfortunately...I guess I will have to study more about Odoo's modules...

Comment: @ンドング一信ndong My answer is actually assuming you were programming in Python and not directly on a server action. The server action must be done a bit differently. I'll try to update my answer with specifics. At the minimum, you do not need any `@api` call, nor a `def ...:` statement.

Comment: Hello Travis, and happy new year. Anything new about the python syntax in the server action?

Comment: Still no answer for this problem? I read that only simple python code can be use in the server action python code box: How simple? what do I have to change in my syntax? the documentation on this subject is really close to nothing...